# Is normalizing an image considered data augmentation?

Tags: python

I'm training a convolutional neural network without data augmentation.
In this code, would that mean getting rid of the transforms.Normalize?

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

Comment: Its not, you use normalization only when the model got pretrained with it e.g. ImageNet models which are pretrained use this normalization and to adapt to the defaults we use the same normalization usually its Normalize(mean [0.485,0.456,0.406], std=[0.229,0.224,0.225])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first question: In my opinion image normalization isn't a real data augmentation technique. Data augmentation is a technique to enhance the size and the quality of a given dataset to avoid overfitting and to improve the generalization ability of your network. Normalization is a technique that helps the CNN to learn faster and better but it doesn't extend your dataset.